# Arduino Project McLightning does not compile

Tags: compiler-errors, arduino, esp8266

I'm trying to run an WS2812 LED Strip with an ESP8266 over a web interface. To do that I found the project [McLightning](https://github.com/toblum/McLighting/releases/tag/v2.2.1).
However the compilation always fails, although I'm following the instructions step by step.
Other blog posts in other forums suggest that package libraries or the ESP board Library are not up to date - but I'm pretty sure I updated all of them.

The board settings are exactly as in the description as well - [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7S29.png).

I uploaded the Error Message [here](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/0l16p0w5zw1odrmm96n7k/McLightning-Error.txt?rlkey=52dgo9qbzg75cz47rrcyggr7t&dl=0), but I don't know what exactly seems to be the problem.

Can some of you perhaps help me with this?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In the log the most crucial lines are:

```
In file included from /Users/username/Documents/Arduino/libraries/WS2812FX-master/src/WS2812FX.h:522,\
                 from /Users/username/Downloads/McLighting-2.2.5/Arduino/McLighting/McLighting.ino:86:\
/Users/username/Documents/Arduino/libraries/WS2812FX-master/src/modes_esp.h:126:3: error: 'typedef struct Mode mode' redeclared as different kind of entity\
  126 | \} mode;\
      |   ^~~~\
In file included from /Users/username/Downloads/McLighting-2.2.5/Arduino/McLighting/McLighting.ino:1:\
/Users/username/Downloads/McLighting-2.2.5/Arduino/McLighting/definitions.h:125:8: note: previous declaration 'MODE mode'\
  125 |   MODE mode = RAINBOW;         // Standard mode that is active when software starts\
      |        ^~~~\
In file included from /Users/username/Documents/Arduino/libraries/WS2812FX-master/src/WS2812FX.h:522,\
                 from /Users/username/Downloads/McLighting-2.2.5/Arduino/McLighting/McLighting.ino:86:\
/Users/username/Documents/Arduino/libraries/WS2812FX-master/src/modes_esp.h:221:33: error: 'mode' does not name a type\
  221 | __attribute__ ((unused)) static mode _modes[] = \{\
      |                                 ^~~~
```

What does it tells you? Someone had a wonderfull idea to name data type as `mode` in a header file and coincidently someone else had similar idea to name varialbe as `mode` in different header (library). And as the `mode` is incredibly common and obvious choice for name when you are using "modes", it just clashed.

What can you do about it:

- rename it in one of the libraries to something more unique (eg. `MODE McLmode = RAINBOW` and replace all occurences) in that library (or your code)
- raise bug and play waiting game

You do both and send the fix in second too...